# Raspberry Pi 2 Netflix

Tags: google-chrome, raspberry-pi, xbmc, netflix, raspberry-pi2

This is not a duplicate of
[this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/how-to-stream-netflix-on-raspbmc), [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17190/netflix-on-the-pi-with-xbmc-any-improvements), or [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/how-to-stream-internet-videos-e-g-netflix-on-a-rasberry-pi-media-player) because [Netflix is now supported on Chrome version 37](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2824623/ubuntu-linux-gets-netflix-without-weird-workarounds.html), meaning that if one installs Chrome on the RPi2, Netflix will work through the browser.

I'd like to be able to stream from OSMC or OpenELEC or Kodi (or XBMC). My guess is that if either of them were to use a Chrome backbone, Netflix would work. Is it realistic to expect a way to allow any of these OSes to begin using Chrome as a backbone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No chrome for arm procs is available to download. chromium will not do it, need the full chrome browser, but can't get it for that processer yet. 
Chrome os is available for arm, but a simple extraction of the libraries and binaries needed won't just make it magically work on a raspi.